# Selected same after the link

Tags: javascript, php

How do I make the selected option stay after link?
I am using the value as href and when it loads it just returns to all. 
What should I do to lock the option value?

Here is my select code:

```
echo ($AppUI->_("Company tickets:") . '<select id="my-select2" name="currentComp">');
echo ('<option value="?m=ticketsmith"/>All') ;
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  if (in_array($row['company_id'], $array1))  {
    echo ('<option value="?m=ticketsmith&amp;ticket_company=' . $row['company_id'] . '" />' . $row['company_id'].', ' . $row["company_name"]) ;
  }
}
```

And here is my JS:

```
document.getElementById("my-select2").onchange = function() {
    localStorage.setItem('my-select2', document.getElementById("my-select2").value);
    window.location.href=this.value;
}
if (localStorage.getItem('my-select2')) {
    document.getElementById("my-select2").options[localStorage.getItem('my-select2')].selected = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Version 1*

```
document.getElementById("my-select2").onchange = function() {
  localStorage.setItem('my-select2', this.value);
  window.location.href=this.value;
}
var val = localStorage.getItem('my-select2');
if (val) {
  document.getElementById("my-select2")[val].selected=true;
}
```

*Version 2* (recommended)

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("my-select2").onchange = function() {
    localStorage.setItem('my-select2', this.selectedIndex);
    window.location.href=this.value;
  }
  var selIdx = localStorage.getItem('my-select2');
  if (selIdx !=null && selIdx !=-1) {
    document.getElementById("my-select2").selectedIndex=selIdx;
  }
}
```

Comment: WOKRED LIKE A CHARM! But before the edit, undo so i could mark as answered :)

Comment: Hi, what do you mean? You prefer another version? This one should work better and is cleaner

Comment: I had a spelling mistake in version 2: `selIdex` instead of `selIdx`

Comment: Is it possible to restore select list to selected="seleceted" when backing?

Comment: What do you mean?? like setAttribute("selected","selected") ? Why?

Comment: I mean that when you select it load page. And when go back to main page it still is selected. I need to refresh to All :)

Comment: You mean `document.getElementById("my-select2").selectedIndex=0;`